# Need clarity on javascript date logic

Tags: javascript, datetime, local-storage

I am getting false for both conditions

```
localStorage.getitem("dl-visited-date") // "Mon Oct 07 2013 13:58:18 GMT-0400 (EDT)";
currentDate // Tue Oct 08 2013 14:18:26 GMT-0400 (EDT)
currentDate > localStorage.getItem("dl-visited-date") //false
currentDate < localStorage.getItem("dl-visited-date") //false
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`localStorage.getitem` does return a *string* (your Date object was implicitly stringified when you stored it in the localstorage). If you compare this with a Date object, both will be casted to numbers, but while this works for the Date object the string will become `NaN`. And that compares `false` to anything.

You will need to parse it before (using the [`Date` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)):

```
var date = new Date(localStorage.getitem("dl-visited-date")),
    currentDate = new Date();
```

If you want to test them for equality, you will need to use plain numbers instead. Use [`Date.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) then:

```
var dateStamp = Date.parse(localStorage.getitem("dl-visited-date")),
    currentDateStamp = Date.now();
```

Comment: How do i convert string into a date or vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    var dateformate = localStorage.getItem("selectedFormat");

    alert(dateformate);
});
```